# Error in creating jquery tabstrip in ASP.NET MVC4

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am not getting the exact visual style of jquery tabstrip in browser (Google Chrome). However i followed the steps of jquery UI procedures not getting the desired result. All Tab contents are displayed on the page without clicking any tab.

My code is:

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>jQuery UI Tabs</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Scripts/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/style.css" />
    <script>
    $(function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
    });
    </script>
    </head>
<body>

<div id="tabs">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Tab1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Tab2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3">Tab3</a></li>
      </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
         <p>Tab1 contents  </p>
    </div>

    <div id="tabs-2">
          <p>Tab2 contents  </p>
    </div>

    <div id="tabs-3">
          <p>Tab3 contents  </p>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Am i missing something? Should i include more java script files? Please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: but i am getting tabs as a list and displayed all contents in paragraphs.

Comment: are you sure JS files are loaded correctly?

Comment: How do i check? I am not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Your code working at jsfiddle.net/z5qWk/

You should check out your script and stylesheet references. Generally this can be done by inspecting browser developer tools and checking errors and network tabs.